# Sqlite.net on "full" .NET console app: possible?

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite-net

I've looked through several questions but can't seem to find the exact answer I'm looking for.  Perhaps I haven't done my search questions the right way! :)

I've set up a SQLite DB3 database for a Xamarin Forms test mobile app I'm developing.  It works very well in a Xamarin Forms project.

I'd like to be able to access the same database through a Windows console app to do the "heavy lifting" of setting up the database for deployment - the mobile app is using it primarily as read only.

Is there any way to use SQLite.Net as a .NET console ORM?  The implementation of things like SQLiteConnectionAsync appear to be mobile (PCL) based only.  To set up the initial database, I did it through cumbersome SQL text commands.  I would love to use the ORM to make adjustments and take advantage of things like LINQ extensions without the need to write a lot of SQL string code.

Have I missed something completely obvious?  Thank you very much for your replies! :)

Comment: Given that SQLite.NET was before Xamarin.Forms, yes. If you have issues with your code, post your code and the error or compilation message. PCL does not mean mobile either. It means portable as in portable between different frameworks

Comment: BTW it seems that your *actual* question is how to seed the database, *not* whether SQLite.net works. *Why* seed the database though? SQLite is a *file* based database. If you want a specific schema, just deploy an empty database with your application

Comment: Thank you for the responses!  I'm pre-seeding the database since it is a large list of data reporting stations across the world. People can add custom sites to it but it's a massive amount of data that needs to be there.

Comment: And I've already been able to seed this database fine - it just involved a lot of SQL commands.  The ORM offered by SQLite.Net is so elegant compared to that and is much more lightweight than frameworks like Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using Entity Framework as your ORM. SQLite is supported by Entity Framework Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/

This article might help:

https://elanderson.net/2017/04/entity-framework-core-with-sqlite/

Comment: Thank you.  I was hoping to avoid Entity since it's so heavy - especially when all I need is basic CRUD.

Comment: You know, for all of the fuss I put up about Entity, the suggestion is excellent.  System.Data.SQLite (using Entity) does exactly what I need.  I'll use SQLite.NET for mobile apps and your suggestion for Windows apps.  Thank you!